# The proper meaning of Bhagava

Tags: terminology, buddha

What is the real meaning of Bhagava? Or are there any multiple meanings?

Sutta references are appreciated.

-Metta

Answer (score 2):

Comments from the following link:

http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/dn/dn.16.1-6.vaji.html

Bhagava: also rendered "the Auspicious One" or "the Exalted One"; the most frequent appellation of the Buddha, though not restricted to Buddhist usage.

The word "Bhagava," can be translated as "the Blessed One"

Answer (score 1):

Bhagava comes from [bhagga](https://suttacentral.net/define/bhagga) + [rāga](https://suttacentral.net/define/r%C4%81ga). That is one how has destroyed lust.

> bhagga -rāga, ˚dosa etc. (in def. of Bhagavā) at Mnd.142 = Cnd.466

Source: [bhagga](https://suttacentral.net/define/bhagga)

Comment: This is an interesting theory although when searching around there seem to be more sources suggesting that the root of the word is the sanskrit "bhaj" meaning something adored

Answer (score 0):

It is many meaning for the buddhanussati practitioner.

See: Recollection of the Enlightened One (buddhanussati) in Visuddhimagga.

http://www.accesstoinsight.org/lib/authors/nanamoli/PathofPurification2011.pdf

Answer (score 0):

The Blessed One (Bhagava)

The Buddha is endowed with the six things: 
 (1) Lordship [Issariya], 
 (2) Doctrine [Dhamma], 
 (3) Fame [Yasa], 
 (4) Glory [Siri], 
 (5) Wish [Kama], and 
 (6) Endeavor [Payatta], 
 thus He is called the Blessed One.

1). He has the supreme lordship over His own mind as follows: 
 i. Anima – power to make the body minute (e.g. making the size of an atom), 
 ii. Laghima – power to make the body light (e.g. walking on air), 
 iii. Mahima – power to make the body huge, 
 iv. Patti – power to arrive where He wants to go, 
 v. Pakamma – power to produce what He wants by resolving, etc., 
 vi. Isita – power to make anyone or anything follow His wishes, 
 vii. Vasita – power to create at will water, fire, etc., and 
 viii. Yatthakamavasayita – power to attain the perfection in all ways in Him who wants to go through the air or do anything else of the sort. 
 2). He has the supramundane Dhamma. 
 3). He has the greatly pure fame, spread through the three worlds, attained through the quality of veracity. 
 4). He has the glory of all limbs, perfect in every appearance, which is capable of comforting the eyes of people eager to see His material body. 
 5). He has the wish i.e., accomplishment of whatever is wanted by Him whether it be for His own benefit or for another’s (others’). 
6). And He has the endeavor, the right effort, which is the reason why the whole world reveres Him.

http://www.tbsa.org/articles/BuddhaQualities.html